# change static array into dynamic with malloc and realloc?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, stdin, realloc

Hallo the following code read the stdin and put it into stdout, but in reverse. I used for this a static array, because I know how much characters are in the input.txt. My question is how can I change my array in a dynamic array(pointer) with using malloc and realloc? All my tries failed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



    int main()
{
    char ch;
    int i,counter;
    char array[50];

    counter = 0;
    i = 0;

    while((ch=getchar()) != EOF)
    {

        array[i] = ch;
        i++;
        counter++;

    }

    for(i = (counter + 1); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%c",array[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you actually tried? Your current code still has the static array.

Comment: I had a lot of errors so I thought it is better to post the code, which works actually.

Comment: Well, if we don't see the code that fails, we can't help with it, can we?

Comment: That sounds right. I will try it again und then I post the code beneath the static array code.

Comment: ok the problem is I don't konw how to use them corretly. A lot of pages have a lot of different ways to use but no way helped me. So can someone help me?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you know that the input you use never has more than 50 characters, you should enforce that limit. When the program is run with arbitrary input, you will eventually access data beyond the array's end.

Anyway, here's your program core, extracted into a function:

```
void rev1()
{
    char array[50];     // Allocate 50 bytes on the stack
    int i = 0;
    char ch;

    while (i < 50 && (ch = getchar()) != EOF) array[i++] = ch;    
    while (i--) putchar(array[i]);
    printf("\n");

    // Do nothing - array goes out of scope
}
```

If you just want to use the same fixed-length buffer on the heap, the code is very similar. You should define a pointer to `char` instead of the array and then call `malloc` in order to obtain the required memory. After you are done using that memory, you must release it with `free`.

Here's a second version that uses memory on the heap:

```
void rev2()
{
    char *array;
    int i = 0;
    char ch;

    array = malloc(50 * sizeof(*array));    // Allocate on the heap
    if (array == NULL) exit(1);             // Check for failure

    while (i < 50 && (ch = getchar()) != EOF) array[i++] = ch;    
    while (i--) putchar(array[i]);
    printf("\n");

    free(array);        // Explicitly release data after use
}
```

Things to note:

- `sizeof(*array)` is `sizeof(char)` in this case, which is always 1 and therefore often is omitted. But `p = malloc(count * sizeof(*p))` is a very useful allocation pattern for allocating an array of `count` elements that will still work if you change the type of the things pointed to.
- Memory allocation on the heap may fail; `malloc` will then return `NULL`. You must cater for such cases. The simple strategy is to just print an error message and abort the program. Depending on what you need the memory for, you might chose other failure strategies.
- Note how the core of the function, the loop is exactly the same as in the first version.
- You also must enforce the limit of 50 chars. The array is on the heap, but it doesn't grow.
- Free the memory after use. If you don't you "leak memory", i.e. you keep chunks of memory blocked. Here, `array` - the pointer variable that holds the array, not the array itself - is a local variable that goes out of scope. Forgetting to `free` the memory here will mean that you lose its address and can't access it again.
- The variable `array` points to the start of the memory. This variable must be passed to `free`.  Don't change this variable, e.g. by incrementing it, otherwise you will lose your "key"  to the memory.

A slightly more involved version re-allocates memory as needed. You can use `realloc` instead of `malloc` if your array grows. The already allocated data stays in place, even if the memory is not the same:

```
void rev3()
{
    char *array = NULL;     // Initially unallocated NULL array
    size_t size = 0;        // Allocated size, initially 0
    int i = 0;
    char ch;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (i >= size) {                    // Check current bounds
            size += 50;                     // Increase memory
            array = realloc(array,          // Reallocate
                size * sizeof(*array));
            if (array == NULL) exit(1);
        }
        array[i++] = ch;    
    }

    while (i--) putchar(array[i]);
    printf("\n");

    free(array);        // Explicitly release data after use
}
```

Notes:

- `realloc(NULL, size)` behaves like `malloc(size)`. Therefore you can implement a reallocation scheme easily by starting with a `NULL` pointer.
- Although the kernel keeps track of the allocated size internally, you have no means to know it, so you must keep track of this information yourself, in this case with `size`.
- Again, you must ensure the the allocation was successful. I've used quick-and-dirty (and silent) program termination above, but you can chose other strategies.
- In this case, the core loop is somewhat more involved. Before appending to the memory, you must check whether you should increase it. After you have populated your memory, access (within the allocated bounds)  is as usual.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void readandprint(void)
{
  int c = getchar();
  if (c == EOF)
    return;
  readandprint();
  printf("%c", c);
  return;
}

int main()
{
  readandprint();
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry,  but I don't understand this answer in case of my question.

Comment: @student96: Did you try it?

Comment: No what should I try with this code?  How can you use a function in itself?

Comment: @student96: It's called `recursion`. Those who do not understand it are doomed to repeat it. And the traditional thing to do with C programs is to compile & run them.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int ch;//It must be int for comparison with the EOF.
    int i, counter;
    char *array = malloc(50);
    int size = 50;

    counter = 0;

    while((ch=getchar()) != EOF){
        array[counter++] = ch;
        if(counter == size){
            char *temp = realloc(array, size += 50);
            if(temp==NULL){
                free(array);
                fprintf(stderr, "realloc error!\n");
                return -1;
            }
            array = temp;
        }
    }

    while(counter){
        printf("%c", array[--counter]);
    }

    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```